# Run Sql select statement in a for / foreach loop

Tags: sql, signals

Hello I'm building a helping app for my students at the school using database and signalr to live update the list.

```
connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [dbo].[HelpLists]", connection))
    {
    command.Notification = null;

    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        messages.Add(item: new Messages { Number = (int)reader["Id"], Message = (string)reader["Name"] });
    }

}
```

The part of the code I want to chance is the `While loop`

Lets say my select statements get 3 rows. Then I would like to pass the `command` through a `for / foreach loop` Kinda like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
         messages.Add(item: new Messages { Number = i + 1, Message = (string)reader["Name"] });
    }
```

Reason is i need the number to start at 1 and increase by 1 for each row in the select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [dbo].[HelpLists]", connection))
    {
    command.Notification = null;

    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
//my change is here
List<reader > readers = new List<reader>();
for(reader rs:readers )
{


System.out.println(rs.id);
System.out.println(rs.name);
}
}
```